# NSAttributedString with sub/superscript on iOS 13

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I maintain an app written in Objective-C and in some places it shows chemical formulas To implement the sub- and superscripts I have this code in an `NSString` extension.

```
- (NSMutableAttributedString *) chemicalFormulaWithFont: (UIFont *) font
{
    if (self.length == 0)
        return nil;

    NSDictionary *normalAttribute = @{NSFontAttributeName: font};
    NSDictionary *baselineAttribute = @{NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName : @0};

    UIFont *smallFont = [UIFont fontWithName: font.fontName
                                        size: font.pointSize * 0.75];

    NSString *superscriptAttributeName = (NSString *)kCTSuperscriptAttributeName;

    NSDictionary *subscriptAttribute = @{superscriptAttributeName : @-1,
                                         NSFontAttributeName: smallFont};

    NSDictionary *superscriptAttribute = @{superscriptAttributeName : @1,
                                           NSFontAttributeName: smallFont};

    NSCharacterSet *decimalDigits = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];

    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: self];

    NSUInteger length = attributedString.length;
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, length);
    [attributedString addAttributes: normalAttribute range: range];

    while (range.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        range = [attributedString.string rangeOfCharacterFromSet: decimalDigits options: 0 range: range];

        if (range.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            unichar ch = [attributedString.string characterAtIndex: range.location - 1];

            if ((ch != '-') && (ch != '+'))
            {
                [attributedString addAttributes: subscriptAttribute range: range];
            }

            range = NSMakeRange(range.location + range.length, length - (range.location + range.length));
        }
    }

    range = NSMakeRange(0, length);

    // if last two characters are +, - , 2+, 3+, 2-, etc then add superscript

    unichar ch = [attributedString.string characterAtIndex: length - 1];

    if ((ch == '-') || (ch == '+'))
    {
        range = NSMakeRange(length - 1, 1);

        ch = [attributedString.string characterAtIndex: length - 2];

        if (ch >= '0' && ch <='9')
            range = NSMakeRange(length - 2, 2);
        [attributedString addAttributes: superscriptAttribute range: range];
    }

    [attributedString addAttributes: baselineAttribute range: range];

    return attributedString;
}
```

The font is "Avenir-Medium"

This worked fine for iOS 12 but on iOS 13 I no longer see the sub and superscripts.

Problem is, my Mac is too old to run Xcode 11 - I am stuck on version 10.2. So I cannot debug this for iOS > 12.1, not even with my iPhone connected (which does run iOS 13).

One thing I could think of is that Avenir-Medium no longer supports this on iOS 13, but it seems unlikely.

Anything else that could have changed in iOS 13 with respect to `NSAttributedString` ?

Comment: This code seems copy-and-pasted directly from your project, but the return statement at the end has the wrong capitalization, which is very suspicious. Was this some kind of typo?

Comment: Yeah, a typo, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I can confirm that this code work in 12.4 and fails in 13.3. Looking at the generated NSAttributedString, it looks fine, so I would suspect a bug in UIKit and would open a Feedback Report about that.

Comment: Found it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58300329/super-subscript-appear-to-be-broken-in-ios13-nsattributedstring

Comment: Change `superscriptAttributeName` to `@"NSSuperScript"`. That seems horrible, and there has to be a better way to get this attribute name, but that definitely works.

Comment: Thanks for finding that! I vaguely remember switching to `kCTSuperscriptAttributeName` because `NSSuperscriptAttributeName` or whatever it was called then didn't work.